# How to change form field description output/markup?

Tags: theming, forms, views

I'm using Physics theme and I can't figure out how to change form fields description output/rendering.

At the moment is it rendered as

```
<div class="description">Lorem</div>
```

while it should be

```
<span class="help-block">Lorem</span>
```

This specific form is a Views exposed filter form but I don't really see that it would differ much from "other forms".

The base theme, Bootstrap, has it's own function for description and it is supposed to render it correctly. However, I don't where this change happens from regarding tag and classes.